# Adding to list inside a Task.Run action in a WebAPI controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to add an item to a list in a *POST* controller method, and then retrieve that data in a separate *GET* method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("add")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddElement([FromBody] Element element)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            lock (o)
            {
                elements.Add(element);
            }
        });

        return Ok();
    } 

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("data")]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        return Ok(elements);
    }
```

However, due to separate threads, elements List is always empty. With or without the lock object, *ConcurrentBag* doesn't work in this case as well.

Comment: `Thread.Run` ?.

Comment: Why not just use a database, and not a flimsy in memory non scalable list?

Comment: Why are you using it like this? Why are you starting a task? Why are you locking the List? Why not use a Thread-safe collection? Please state the actual problem your are trying to solve, instead of us debugging your not-so-good solution.

Comment: @TheGeneral database?  Talking about complecting...

Comment: Where is `elements` declared? Is your class a singleton or do you get new instances of with every request?

Answer (score 0):

With `async` and `await` you are prone to race conditions, which you may experience - while processing request to add element to list, you try to get its items. This may happen if procesing post request is being processed.

To overcome this you would need to also synchronize getting items with adding items. This could be done using the same lock object and `lock` statement.

But I would recommend using `SemaphoreSlim`, more reliable way of synchronization between threads.

Comment: We have [thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) for that... not necessary to reinvent the wheel. (unless you have very specific needs...